# Will the installation of Visual Studio 11 Express overwrite Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8-preview, version

I want to install Visual Studio 11 Express Beta to to create some metro apps, just for fun. I still want to keep Visual Studio 2010 as my primary development environment and have no intention to reinstall it later.

If I install VS11 Express, will it keep VS2010 as it is now, or it will imagine that I want to upgrade to the later version, and erase/damage the old one, and the only solution I have is to install VS11 on a virtual machine?

In other words, is a side-by-side scenario is supported for different versions of Visual Studio?

---

After trying myself, installing Visual Studio 11 Express Beta on the same machine is definitely **not a safe thing** to do. Now that I installed it, it is impossible to compile any project in Visual Studio 2010: for every project, an "exited with code 9009" error appears.

So if you're in the same case, just setup a virtual machine for VS11, especially while there is Windows 8 Consumer Preview available for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all previous (beta) versions of Visual Studio, the side-by-side installation was no problem at all.

What always was a problem for me was the beta frameworks that come with it.

I'm not installing a beta on a production system any time soon. That's for sure.